# SQl/DB2 - Only show rows that exists 3 or more times

Tags: sql, db2

with this Statement I get the following result:

```
SELECT Employee.Lastname, Employee.Firstnme, EMP_ACT.Projno
FROM Employee Join EMP_ACT 
On Employee.Empno = EMP_Act.Empno
```

result:

```
HAAS            CHRISTINE    AD3100
PULASKI         EVA          AD3110
JEFFERSON       JAMES        AD3111
JEFFERSON       JAMES        AD3111
JEFFERSON       JAMES        AD3111
JEFFERSON       JAMES        AD3111
JEFFERSON       JAMES        AD3111
```

And now I want to display only rows that exists 3 or more times. The last column should display the number of Projno.

e.g.:  JEFFERSON       JAMES     5

I tried it this way:

```
GROUP BY Projno HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

but I always get errors :/

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to group by all of the non-aggregate columns used in the select statement.

```
SELECT Employee.Lastname, Employee.Firstnme, EMP_ACT.Projno, COUNT(*)
    FROM Employee 
        Join EMP_ACT 
            On Employee.Empno = EMP_Act.Empno
    GROUP BY Employee.Lastname, Employee.Firstnme, EMP_ACT.Projno
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```